# Translate class function to lambda function

Tags: php

I'm trying to pull of something like this:

```
class helper {
   .. some class variables ..

   public function somehelper ($somevar) 
   {
            .. some action ..
   }
}
```

to - `$somehelper('somevar!')`

i want it to be a lambda function without me declaring a new lambda function. I want the code to be created automatically. I want to create this lambda function autamatically via a core class that will create to each helper function - lambda function with the functions name. I dont want to specify it. I have a template file included, and an instance of a class helper. `<a href..><?= $makeSeo($url); ?></a>` this will lead to - public function `makeSeo($url)` in a helper class. autmatically.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Not sure what the question is. Can you elaborate?

Comment: *(reference)* [Anonymous functions](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want something to create a lambda given a method name? Assuming your 'Helper' class methods are static, something like this would do it

```
function makeHelper($fn)
{
   //note use of PHP5.3 closure syntax
   $helper = function($param) use ($fn) {
       return Helper::$fn($param);
   };

   return $helper;
}

//create a new lambda
$foo=makeHelper('somehelper');

//call it...
$foo('Hello world);
```

Comment: its a progress, but no - I dont want to specify it. I have a template file included, and an instance of a class helper.
<a href..><?= $makeSeo($url); ?></a>
this will lead to - public function makeSeo($url) in a helper class. autmatically.

Comment: Nice example, Paul. Great use of PHP 5.3!

Comment: @WEBProject I think you need to clarify *why* you want to do this.

Comment: I want to use it in view (tpl) files

Comment: OK, well how about you use the reflection API to find all the methods in a class, and set up the lambdas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're saying that you want the variable `$somehelper` to call `helper::somehelper` from outside the context of the class.

```
$somehelper = function($somevar) {
    return helper::somehelper($somevar);
});
```

This presume that the `somehelper` is intended to be a static function (i.e. should be marked as `public static function`. If it is not, you're going to have to provide more information about where the class instance comes from.

Comment: its a start, but no - i want it to be a lambda function without me declaring a new lambda function. I want the code that you genrated to be created automatically.

Comment: @WEBProject Created automatically by what?

Comment: I want to create this lambda function autamatically via a core class that will create to each helper function - lambda function with the functions name