# Generating lambda function from eval()

Tags: php, eval, php-5.3

I have few helpers - I want to redclare each helper's method as a lambda anonymous function.

I'm trying to do it by getting the helpers methods, and then doing an eval function, but it wont work, im getting parse error..

My current code:

```
            foreach($this->helpers as $helper)
            {
                include(master_path . 'helpers/'.$helper.'Helper.php');

                $helperClass = new applicationHelper();
                $methods = get_class_methods($helperClass);
                foreach($methods as $method )
                {

                    eval ( "\$$method = function (\$text) {
                        \$helperClass->$method(\$text);
                    }");

                }
             }
```

Due to efficiency fears - I'd like a better solution if you know it, thanks!
Thanks Guys!

Comment: How is that question different from your [Translate class function to lambda function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836258/translate-class-function-to-lambda-function)

Comment: i'm not asking you to give me an explanation how to do it - cause i already did, but its buggy. anyway, already got my answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work:

```
foreach($methods as $method )
{
    $$method = function($text) use ($method, $helperClass) {
        return $helperClass->$method($text);
    }
}
```

But still dont know why are you doing that.

**EDIT** 
PHP 5.3.x needed -> look here [Anonymous funcions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($this->helpers as $helper) {
    include(master_path . 'helpers/'.$helper.'Helper.php');

    $helperClass = new applicationHelper();
    foreach (get_class_methods($helperClass) as $method) {
        $$method = function($text) use($helperClass, $method) {
            $helperClass->$method($text);
        };
    }
}
```

That get's rid of the slow `eval`.